# Combing different SHMs which are in the same direction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vectors, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

Our teacher taught us this method for combining different SHMs he didn't really give a lot of formal defination etc he just said us about the algorithm to solve it as shown in the picture what seemed logical to me was to just add $x_1+x_2$ and solve it mathematically and it works what I don't understand is why writing these SHMs as vectors (as in the image) and adding like normal vectors give the same answer I want to know the reasoning behind this method of why is it correct.I know I am supposed to share what I've searched on it till now but Since our teacher didn't really say about the formal terms I was unable to frame my question properly so that I get the desired result in Google

Comment: It is necessary for such vector trickery to work because it is coming from a mathematically proved link between circles and SHM. In particular, it is known that the perfect projection shadow of a uniform circular motion along one of its sides is precisely an SHM. It must then be possible to use radial position vectors to reason about SHM, really, trigonometry. You can very easily prove this for yourself if you learn about complex exponentials (phasors) later on.

Answer (score 0):

The type of diagram your teacher used is called a [phasor diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor). If you are giving the JEE you'll learn all about phasor diagrams!

These diagrams are mostly used for analysing electrical circuits when we have an AC voltage that is sinusoidal, but they can be used anywhere that you have quantities oscillating sinusoidally with time. In particular they offer a simple graphical way to see what happens when you add two sine waves with different phases.